# how to get the display the content of one page but clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

i have a page having some contents plus a edit button So when you hit the edit button it will show the 2nd page. I want it as if both are in only one page. it will look like the last name(text area is converted into text field)Please tell me how to do it
the screen shot is

and the source code is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- The new doctype -->
<html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>home</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />



    </head>

    <body>

        <section id="page" > <!-- Defining the #page section with the section tag -->

            <header > <!-- Defining the header section of the page with the appropriate tag -->

                <hgroup>
                    <h1>Your Logo</h1>
                    <h3>and a fancy slogan</h3>
                </hgroup>

                <nav class="clear"> <!-- The nav link semantically marks your main site navigation -->
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#article1">My Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#article2">Change password</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#article3">Navigation Menu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </header>

            <section id="articles"> <!-- A new section with the articles -->

                <!-- Article 1 start -->

                <div class="line"></div>  <!-- Dividing line -->

                <article id="article1"> <!-- The new article tag. The id is supplied so it can be scrolled into view. -->
                    <h2>Dr. Sukant Kumar nayak</h2>

                    <div class="line"></div>

                    <div class="articleBody clear">



                     <div >

        <div style="float: left; padding-left: 50px; padding-top: 5px">
            <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" >
            <tr>
                <td width="200" height="30">
                    <b>Last Name</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <label for="LastName">LastName</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="30">
                    <b>First Name</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="30">
                    <b>Date of Birth</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="DateofBirth">Date of Birth</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="30">
                    <b>Qualification</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="LastName">Qualification</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="30">
                    <b>Registration. No.</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="RegistrationNo">Registration No</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="30">
                    <b>Country of Registration</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="CountryofRegistration">Country of Registration</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="30">
                    <b>Practice Name</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="PracticeName">Practice Name</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="30">
                    <b>Phone</b>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <label for="Phone">Phone</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="30">
                    <b>Email</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="Email">Email</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td  height="30">
                    <b></b>
                </td>
                <td align="right" >
                    <label for="Email"><input type="submit" class="button button-submit" value="Edit" /></label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        </div>
        <div style="float: right;padding-right: 50px;padding-top: 50px">

            <table>

                <tr>
                <td width="160" height="30">
                    <b>Address</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="Address">Address</label>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  height="30">
                        <b>Street</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="Street">Street</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  height="30">
                        <b>City</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="City">City</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  height="30">
                        <b>State</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="State">State</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  height="30">
                        <b>Country</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="Country">Country</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  height="30">
                        <b>Pin Code</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="PinCode">Pin Code</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  height="30">
                        <b>How do you know?</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="HowDoYouKnow">How Do You Know</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  height="30">
                        <b>Comment</b>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <label for="Comments">Comments</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table><div  align="center" style="padding-top: 30px">

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <!-- Article 1 end -->


                <!-- Article 2 start -->

                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="space"></div>                <div class="space"></div>                <div class="space"></div>                <div class="space"></div>
<div class="space"></div><div class="space"></div><div class="space"></div><div class="space"></div><div class="space"></div><div class="space"></div><div class="space"></div>
<div class="space"></div><div class="space"></div><div class="space"></div><div class="space"></div><div class="space"></div><div class="space"></div>
                <article id="article2">
                    <h2>Change Password</h2>

                    <div class="line"></div>

                    <div class="articleBody clear">
                        <figure>
                            <img src="medical.jpg" width="620" height="440" /></a>
                        </figure>

                        <p><div align="center" style="padding-top: 30px">
            <table  cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
                <tr>
                    <td width="200" height="30"><h5>Old Password</h5></td>
                    <td  height="30"><input name="old" type="password"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  height="30"><h5>New Password</h5></td>
                    <td  height="30"><input name="newPsw" type="password"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="30"><h5>Confirm Password</h5></td>
                    <td  height="30"><input name="confirm" type="password"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-bar"  align="center" style="padding-top: 30px">
            <table align="center" >
                <tr >
                    <td width="100" align="center"><input type="submit" class="button button-submit" value="Submit"  /></td>
                    <td width="100" align="center"><input type="reset" class="button button-submit" value="Reset" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div></p>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <!-- Article 2 end -->

                <!-- Article 3 start -->

                <div class="line"></div>



                <!-- Article 3 end -->


            </section>

        <footer> <!-- Marking the footer section -->

           <div class="line"></div>

           <p>Copyright 2013 - mysite.com</p> 

           <a href="#" class="up">Go UP</a>
           <a href="www.df.com" class="by">dh</a>


        </footer>

        </section> <!-- Closing the #page section -->

        <!-- JavaScript Includes -->

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

when you hit the edit button the this should this display

![enter image description here][2]
 the source code is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- The new doctype -->
<html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>home</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />



    </head>

    <body>

        <section id="page" > <!-- Defining the #page section with the section tag -->

            <header > <!-- Defining the header section of the page with the appropriate tag -->

                <hgroup>
                    <h1>Your Logo</h1>
                    <h3>and a fancy slogan</h3>
                </hgroup>

                <nav class="clear"> <!-- The nav link semantically marks your main site navigation -->
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#article1">My Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#article2">Change password</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#article3">Navigation Menu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </header>

            <section id="articles"> <!-- A new section with the articles -->

                <!-- Article 1 start -->

                <div class="line"></div>  <!-- Dividing line -->

                <article id="article1"> <!-- The new article tag. The id is supplied so it can be scrolled into view. -->
                    <h2>Dr. Sukant Kumar nayak</h2>

                    <div class="line"></div>

                    <div class="articleBody clear">



                     <div >

        <div style="float: left; padding-left: 50px; padding-top: 50px">
            <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" >
            <tr>
                <td width="200" height="30">
                    <b>Last Name</b>
                    <p style="float:right; color: red ">*   </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="LastName" type="text" value="<%=lastName %>"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="30">
                    <b>First Name</b>
                    <p style="float:right; color: red ">*   </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="FirstName" type="text" value="<%=firstName %>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="30">
                    <b>Date of Birth</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="DateofBirth" type="text" value="<%=DOB %>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="30">
                    <b>Qualification</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="Qualification" type="text" value="<%=Qualification %>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="30">
                    <b>Registration. No.</b>
                    <p style="float:right; color: red ">*   </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="RegistrationNo" type="text" value="<%=RegistrationNo %>"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="30">
                    <b>Country of Registration</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="CountryofRegistration" type="text" value="<%=CountryOfRegistration %>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="30">
                    <b>Practice Name</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="PracticeName" type="text" value="<%=PracticeName %>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="30">
                    <b>Phone</b>
                    <p style="float:right; color: red ">*   </p>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input name="Phone" type="text" value="<%=Phone %>"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="30">
                    <b>Email</b>
                    <p style="float:right; color: red ">*   </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="Email" type="text" value="<%=Email %>"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="30">
                    <b>Image</b>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input name="Image" type="file" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        </div>
        <div style="float: right;padding-right: 50px;padding-top: 50px">
            <table>
                <tr>
                <td width="160" height="30">
                    <b>Address</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="Address" type="text" value="<%=Address %>"/>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  height="30">
                        <b>Street</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="Street" type="text" value="<%=Street %>" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  height="30">
                        <b>City</b>
                        <p style="float:right; color: red ">*   </p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="City" type="text" value="<%=City %>" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  height="30">
                        <b>State</b>
                        <p style="float:right; color: red ">*   </p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="State" type="text" value="<%=State %>" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  height="30">
                        <b>Country</b>
                        <p style="float:right; color: red ">*   </p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="Country" type="text" value="<%=country %>" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  height="30">
                        <b>Pin Code</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="PinCode" type="text" value="<%=PinCode %>" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  height="30">
                        <b>How do you know?</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="HowDoYouKnow" type="text" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  height="30">
                        <b>Comment</b>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <textarea  name="Comments" cols="15" rows="5" readonly></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="footer-bar"  align="center" style="padding-top: 30px">
            <table align="center" >
                <tr >
                    <td width="100" align="center"><input type="submit" class="button button-submit" value="Submit"  /></td>
                    <td width="100" align="center"><input type="reset" class="button button-submit" value="Reset" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div></p>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <!-- Article 2 end -->

                <!-- Article 3 start -->

                <div class="line"></div>



                <!-- Article 3 end -->


            </section>

        <footer> <!-- Marking the footer section -->

           <div class="line"></div>

           <p>Copyright 2013 - mysite.com</p> 

           <a href="#" class="up">Go UP</a>
           <a href="www.df.com" class="by">dh</a>


        </footer>

        </section> <!-- Closing the #page section -->

        <!-- JavaScript Includes -->

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Praveen said, you don't need two different pages, but two divs in the same page, and then use some javascript to switch between the display/visibility of the two. You can do this with two different classess per element, which the classes having different properties for display (`display:none` and `display:block`) or visibility (`visibilty: hidden` and `visibility:visible`).

JQuery `toggle()` method is a straightforward option:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

But mind that it toggles `display`, so it will affect your layout (`display:none`  affects your layout, while `visibility:hidden does not`), which is something probably you don't want. One way to avoid this (but I am not 100% sure this is the best way to do it) is to insert each div (`position:absolute`) within another div (`position:relative`)

Answer (score 0):

apply a css class which you want to display.By clicking on button show those fields only.

Comment: can you please give me some hint

Answer (score 0):

Just Make two div.. One div with the first image contents and second div with second image content. and once u clicked edit button just hide the first div and display second div.....

Comment: u dont want to hide the content one by one.. just make a big div which includes every field..  and make it display none...